# Special filtering of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I am attempting to filter the following data frame:

```
calendar <- data.frame(Account_Num,Account_Num_Spec,Billing_Num,Transaction_Amt2,color,CAL_DATE2)
```

In the following manner:

For all rows that have the same contents in the "Account_Num_Spec", "Billing_Num" and "color" - filter them into one row that has the sum of "Transaction_Amt2" and the first oldest date in "CAL_DATE2".

For example

```
    Ac_Num   AC_Num_Spec  Bill_Num   Amount   Color   Date
1    1162     1162-001     620919      10      red    10/12/19 
2    1179     1179-001     790719      10      red    11/12/19
3    1172     1172-001     721119      10      red    12/12/19
4    1162     1162-001     620919      -5      red    09/12/19
5    1162     1162-001     621019      10      red    11/12/19
6    1179     1179-001     791119      10      green  11/12/19
7    1162     1162-002     620919      10      red    12/12/19
8    1179     1179-001     791079      10      green  10/12/19
```

goes to:

```
    Ac_Num   AC_Num_Spec  Bill_Num   Amount   Color   Date
1    1162     1162-001     620919       5      red    09/12/19 
2    1179     1179-001     790719      10      red    11/12/19
3    1179     1179-001     791119      10      red    12/12/19
4    1172     1172-001     721119      10      red    12/12/19
5    1162     1162-001     621019      10      red    11/12/19
6    1179     1179-001     791119      10      green  11/12/19
7    1162     1162-002     620919      10      red    12/12/19
8    1179     1179-001     791079      10      green  10/12/19
```

Comment: That is a simple aggregation. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using `group_by` and `summarize` within the `dplyr` package should work for what you are asking

```
calendar %>%
    group_by(Account_Num,Account_Num_Spec,Billing_Num, color) %>%
    summarize(Amount = sum(Amount),
              Date = max(Date))
```

I know you didn't specify that `Account_Num` had to be matching, but from your example that looked to be the case so I included it within the `group_by` function.